# Greater than and less than symbol in regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I am new to regular expressions, and I am just tired by really studying all of the regex charatcer and all. I need to know what is the purpose of greater than symbol in regex for eg:

```
preg_match('/(?<=<).*?(?=>)/', 'sadfas<email@email.com>', $email);
```

Please tell me the use of greater than symbo and less than symbol in regex.

Comment: It's a literal matching the last `>` in the target string.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html
links to:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html#gnu

Comment: i didnt understand can you please describe me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The greater than symbol simply matches the literal `>` at the end of your target string.

The less than symbol is not so simple. First let's review the lookaround syntax:

The pattern `(?<={pattern})` is a positive lookbehind assertion, it tests whether the currently matched string is preceded by a string matching `{pattern}`.

The pattern `(?={pattern})` is a positive lookahead assertion, it tests whether the currently matched string is followed by a string matching `{pattern}`.

So breaking down your expression

- `(?<=<)` assert that the currently matched string is preceded by a literal `<`
- `.*?` match anything zero or more times, lazily
- `(?=>)` assert than the currently matched string is followed by a literal `>`

Putting it all together the pattern will extract `email@email.com` from the input string you have given it.

Comment: nice answer.  Worth noting negative lookahead "?!" and negative lookbehind "?<!"

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is using lookarounds to capture email address between `<` and `>` characters. In your example input it captures `email@email.com`.

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=<) Positive Lookbehind - Assert that the regex below can be matched
< matches the character < literally
.*? matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible,
expanding as needed [lazy]
(?=>) Positive Lookahead - Assert that the regex below can be matched
> matches the character > literally
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/yH6tY8

Comment: Hope now you have understood with these answers :)

Comment: no i dindt understood the use of (?=<) in regex ? others i understood

Comment: As I wrote in my answer. `(?<=...)` is the syntax for `Positive Lookbehind` and `(?<=<)` makes sure the matched text is immediateley preceded by a literal `<`.

Comment: Yes I am but hardly active there. I prefer LinkedIn OR Twitter (both available in my profile link here).

Comment: can you add me on fb ?..www.facebook.com/youngvijay

Comment: That's an impressive website